# How to get value from webpage?

Tags: excel, vba, web

I want to get/input value to webpage.

All my effort so far works until web loading only. I have no knowledge in web. I can't provide the website link as it's an *intranet* web.

`done lin.e 50` is the place where I want to put my input

then click `save button`

```
<td valign="top" class="s bgltgray">
    <textarea id="txtResponse1" name="txtResponse1" cols="80" rows="3" class="s">done lin.e 50.</textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="cmdRespond1" name="cmdRespond1" value="Save" onclick="cmdRespond_click(1);">
    <br> Latest Response By: samyvelu, On: 10/23/2017
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. Can't really test it since i dont have the url, but this code have worked on another url just without the textarea Tag name

```
Sub IEtest()
Dim ie As Object
Dim i, x As Integer
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With ie
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "" '<--- CHANGE THIS

    Do While ie.busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Set objCollection = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")

    i = 0

    While i < objCollection.Length
        If objCollection(i).Name = "txtResponse1" Then
            objCollection(i).Value = "Your input" '<--- CHANGE THIS
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Wend

    Set objCollection = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")

    i = 0

    While i < objCollection.Length

        If objCollection(i).Type = "submit" And objCollection(i).Name = "cmdRespond1" Then
            Set objElement = objCollection(i)
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Wend

    objElement.Click
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Nesset, Thanks for the code. unfortunately, it does not work with error msg unspecified error/automation error. And error causing at line "Set objCollection = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")"

Comment: You could try and change it to `Set objCollection = ie.Document.getElementsByID("txtResponse1")`. I've never seen the error you are describing, so don't know why it's accuring. Will try to make a html code with textarea to test when I home later today.

Comment: Well just got home and made a fast test site with basic html elements and I got the same error as you. I found out that there is a difference if you are on Internet and Local Intranet. When it's on Local Intranet you have to change `Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")` to `Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium` and add the refference 'Microsoft Internet Controls' (VBAEditor >Tools > Refferences)

Comment: Wow! It works. Thank you very much, Nesset! Really appreciated! I'm going to start my project now based on your input. Again thank you.

Comment: You are most welcome, after looking over the code again I'm fairly sure it can be optimized abit. Will try to make it better after work :)

Comment: T. Nesset, how are you :). I have a new problem with web scrapping on Silverlight websites... do yu have any idea how to work with Silverlight website?

Comment: @Semy I'm good, thanks for asking, and you? 
- I've used simular methode on silverlight websites before. If you are able to send me a link for the site, I'll take a look on it :)

Comment: Hi Nesset, could please help me on similar case for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54087421/vba-web-scrapping-get-value-from-href

Comment: Hi @Semy,that question has been taken down.

Comment: I try to use your previous code to achieve the same objective. I managed to go until the last step to inner text, however not return value.. prompt errors. could you please help me how to get those digits?  .
.
<td>
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdResult_HSCode$ctl02$ctl00','')">29091900</a>
</td>
<td>2909191800</td>

Answer (score 1):

There are ids present. Use those as they are the fastest selector method. Using InternetExplorerMedium object

```
With ie.document
    .getElementById("txtResponse1").value = "yourValue"
    .getElementById("cmdRespond1").Click '.Submit
End With
```